# Very basic chatbot

Tags: lua

Was the best way to implent this? For example it will only say "It's nice I know." If you first ask "hat" and then answer "yes".

This is how I'm thinking:

```
Topic = 0

local messages = {
    {"name", "I'm Bob, the owner of this little shop."},
    {"job", "I sell stuff."},
    {"hat|head", "You like my hat?", Topic = 1},
    {Topic == 1, "yes", "It's nice I know."}}

for i, a in ipairs(messages) do
    if isMsg(a[1], msg) then
        makeSay(a[2])
        return true
    end
end
```

Functions

```
function isMsg(messages, msg)
    local keys = split(messages, "|")
    if getmsg(keys, msg) then
        return true
    end
    return false
end

function table.contains(table, element)
    for _, value in ipairs(table) do
        if value == element then
            return true
        end
    end
    return false
end

function getmsg(t, msg)
    for v, a in ipairs(t) do
        if msgcontains(msg, a) then
            return true
        end
    end
    return false
end

function keyContains(t, msg)
    for v, t in ipairs(t) do
        if t == msg then
            return true
        end
    end
    return false
end

function split(str, pat)
    local t = {} -- NOTE: use {n = 0} in Lua-5.0
    local fpat = "(.-)" .. pat
    local last_end = 1
    local s, e, cap = str:find(fpat, 1)
    while s do
        if s ~= 1 or cap ~= "" then
            table.insert(t,cap)
        end
        last_end = e+1
        s, e, cap = str:find(fpat, last_end)
    end
    if last_end <= #str then
        cap = str:sub(last_end)
        table.insert(t, cap)
    end
    return t
end
```

Answer (score 7):

I see a lot of problems here...

- are the answers selectable in the GUI? If not such predefined answers are not quite user-friendly, prone to typos etc.
- You might have to escape strings with "|" then unescape them. Yes chances are low, but that's how bugs start.
- Use closures. Do not redefine your table every time you run that function
- `for k,v in ipairs(tbl)` is a lot slower than `for i, #tbl do`
- Is there an actual difference between `keyContains` and `table.contains`?

### Use Hash-Tables

Lua has a pretty fast implementation of them, so your decision code could be made a lot faster - and easier to read like this

```
local messages = {
    ["name"] = "I'm Bob, the owner of this little shop.",
    ["job"] = "I sell stuff.",
}

function getanswer(question)
    return messages[question];
end
```

- Since Lua hashes all strings anyway you will almost always win using hashtables.
- Your string can contain any value
- it's a lot easier to read.

Now for the topics. I will skip the part where you "revert" from topics, since you have to know yourself whether you need to "cancel out" or "time out" or don't allow it in general.

```
local messages = {
    [1] = "Hello stranger!",
    ["name"] = "I'm Bob, the owner of this little shop.",
    ["job"] = "I sell stuff.",
    ["hat"] = {
         [1] = "You like my hat?",
         ["yes"] = "It's nice I know.",
         ["no"] = "You ...!",
    },
}
local topic = messages;

function getanswer(question)
    if type(topic[question]) == "table" then
        topic = topic[question];
        return topic[1];
    else
        return topic[question];
    end
end
```

You could also implement random answers quite easily by just adding more integer key values and selecting one with `math.random(1, #topic)`

if there are duplicate topics, just duplicate the table. Yeah it looks like a big overhead but in most cases it doesn't really matter. An alternative is just referencing the table like

```
messages.head = messages.hat;
```

Though that might get hard to maintain. There are other options but my answer would just get longer and longer...